# Using multithreading in Server application (written with and for deployment to Google App Engine)

Tags: java, multithreading, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, google-cloud-datastore

I'm developing an enrollment application. The client side is an Android application enabling the client to enter their information which are stored using the data storage service of the Google cloud and the images are entered are stored using the blob storage service.

The server side is a J2EE application extracting the data and blobs entered previously and doing some tests such as face recognition, alphanumeric matching etc. These tests are done asynchronously and continuously.I thaught to use the multithreading for these processes done by the server side.

So is that recommended for such case ? Is there other solution ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several limitations in GAE that somewhat limit it's multiprocessing abilities:

1. Each request can make up to 50 threads, but threads can not outlive the request, which itself has a 60 seconds limit. Also, threads must be created via GAE's own [`ThreadManager`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/ThreadManager), which limits the use of most external processing libraries.
2. Background threads independent of current request are available and can be long-lived, but there is a limit of 10 background threads per instance.

For async processing you should look into [Task Queues](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/) - it has all above limitations, but can run for 10 minutes. You can start periodic processing via [Cron jobs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron).

Note that GAE instances are quite limited ([default is single core 600MHz, 128Mb RAM](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings)). They are also quite expensive given how low-power they are. If you need more processing power you should look into [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/products/compute-engine/) (powerful, stand-alone, unmanaged, no GAE-services access, fairly priced for the power), or in your case preferably [Managed VMs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/) (powerful, managed, limited GAE-service access, same price as CE).

So if you have light processing, use Task Queues, if you need more power use Managed VMs (currently in preview).